# Is there a way to recover original template template class enbeded in boost mpl quote?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost, boost-mpl

I quoted a template class to put it into a mpl::vector doing this:

```
boost::mpl::vector<int, boost::mpl::quote2<std::pair>>
```

Then, I obtained the 2nd element like this:

```
using A=typename boost::mpl::at<T, boost::mpl::int_<2>>::type;
```

I need now to pass the original template class to a class like this:

```
template<class A, template<class, class> class C>
class B{
    C<A, B*> _c;
};
```

I'm tried using apply or bind, but couldn't find the way to make B accept the second parameter.

I get errors of the kind:

```
error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template
```

edit:

Example code:

```
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/quote.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>

template<class, class> class A{};
template<class A, template<class, class> class C>
class B{
    C<A, B*> _c;
};
using T=boost::mpl::vector<int, boost::mpl::quote2<A>> ;
using T1=typename boost::mpl::at<T, boost::mpl::int_<0>>::type;
using T2=typename boost::mpl::at<T, boost::mpl::int_<1>>::type;

int main(){
    B<T1, T2> b;
    return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template B<T1, T2> b;
```

Comment: template< class A, template< class, class> class C > should just be template< class A, class C >

Comment: No, actually that is working. The meaning is that you expect one template class with 2 template parameters. The code not working is the one using the mpl for qouting, I'm trying to get something to unquote afterward.

Comment: One class template, not one template class – this is the discerning factor. ;-]

Comment: Please post a minimal and complete example showing your issue. Also, MPL vectors are 0-indexed, so the 2nd element of a vector would be `mpl::at<V, mpl::int_<1>>::type` instead of `mpl::at<V, mpl::int_<2>>::type`.

Comment: Oh, sorry about the 2, it was because my code has 3 parameters and it wanted to simplify, forgot to change the 2 to 1. Writting a complete example now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPL is still largely a C++03 lib AFAIK and you're trying to make it generate something that didn't conceptually exist before C++11.  I suspect that having `quote` work in that case is a coincidence of syntax rather than intended functionality.

The following code compiles successfully in VC2013:

```
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/quote.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/apply.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>

template<class, class> class A{};
template<class A, template<class, class> class C>
class B{
    C<A, B*> _c;
};
using T = boost::mpl::vector < int, boost::mpl::quote2<A> > ;
using T1 = boost::mpl::at<T, boost::mpl::int_<0>>::type;
using T2 = boost::mpl::at<T, boost::mpl::int_<1>>::type;

template<typename X1, typename X2>
using TT2 = typename boost::mpl::apply<T2, X1, X2>::type;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    B<T1, TT2> b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it was my first guess :)
I got an error about clang saying "template needs symbol after template" or similar, tracked it down to a bug report saying that "template alias" wasn't fully working. I'm updating clang to svn version to see if that is possible while I'm trying to figure out an alternative solution.

Comment: Given your example code, I've updated my answer to include a working (or at least compiling) version.  Albeit not tested on clang, and with terrible identifier names. :)

Comment: That's interesting, it works when defined out of main.
I'm trying to use same code inside a BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE and getting: "error: expected expression", same if I move the usings inside the main, error is triggered by the using TT2 line.

Comment: Last version of clang doesn't make it better.

Comment: Looks like a dead end for now, anyway the reply answers the original question, thanks!.